# Why java thread behaves differently when counter is larger in my class?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    static int x = 25;
    int y = 0;
    private static final Object sharedLock = new Object();


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(x>0){
            someMethod();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void someMethod(){
        synchronized (sharedLock){
            x--;
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
public class MyRunnableClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyRunnableClass aa = new MyRunnableClass();
        MyRunnableClass bb = new MyRunnableClass();

        Thread a = new Thread(aa);
        Thread b = new Thread(bb);

        a.start();
        b.start();

        a.join();
        b.join();

        System.out.println(aa.y + bb.y);

    }
}
```

When I run this code as it is I see output 25 which is fine, but when x is 250, I see 251.. Why? Why not 250?

Comment: If you run again and again with x=25 you will see the same effect also, because you have race condition.

Comment: Making x volatile does not make any difference @user3580294

Comment: Well never mind then... But the point about the different value of `x` still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing:

```
    while(x>0){
        someMethod();
    }
```

Let's say x = 1 and:

Thread A evaluates x > 0 to true, and enters the loop.
Let's say Thread A gets interrupted before the next line executes.
Thread B will also evaluates x > 0 to true and enter the loop.

Both will decrement x one after the other and increment their y.

To solve this, the check for x > 0 must be in the lock as well.

Ex:

```
public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

static int x = 25;
int y = 0;
private static final Object sharedLock = new Object();


@Override
public void run() {
    while(x>0){
        someMethod();
    }
}

public synchronized void someMethod(){
    synchronized (sharedLock){
        if(x > 0){
            x--;
            y++;
       }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You have to extend the `synchronized` scope, so that is also covers the read operation on `x`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for (;;) {
        synchronized (sharedObject) {
            if (x <= 0) break;
            someMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Coincidence.  The same thing could happen with `25`, just like any other number.

For example, during execution of

```
while(x>0){
    someMethod();
}
```

which is not synchronized over, after a bunch of looping, let's take `x` to be 1. The first thread starts iterating (enters the body), then threads switch, the second thread sees `x` is 1, so enters the loop body as well. Both will increment their count and their sum will be equal to one more than the original `x` value.

This is a race condition and you just happen to see the consequences more easily with larger numbers.

Comment: Comments deleted? Why?

Comment: @KorayTugay I edited my answer to reflect what was said.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, both Thread a and Thread b can call someMethod() because x was 1. One Thread locks the sharedLock, makes x equal to 0, y equal to 250 and then release the sharedLock, at which point the other thread calls someMethod() and makes y equal to 251 and x equal to -1.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve that problem with `AtomicInteger`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable {

    private static final AtomicInteger xHolder = new AtomicInteger(25);
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (xHolder.decrementAndGet() >= 0) {
            y++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyRunnableClass aa = new MyRunnableClass();
        MyRunnableClass bb = new MyRunnableClass();

        Thread a = new Thread(aa);
        Thread b = new Thread(bb);

        a.start();
        b.start();

        a.join();
        b.join();

        System.out.println(aa.y + bb.y);
    }
}
```

Or with some extended parallelism to test:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyRunnableClass implements Callable<Integer> {

    private static final AtomicInteger xHolder = new AtomicInteger(250000);
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {                
        while (xHolder.decrementAndGet() >= 0) {
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " returns " + y);
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ExecutorCompletionService<Integer> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(
                executorService);

        int parallelism = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < parallelism; ++i) {
            completionService.submit(new MyRunnableClass());
        } // for

        int ySum = 0;       
        for (int j = 0; j < parallelism; ++j) {
            Future<Integer> future = completionService.take();          
            ySum += future.get();
        } // for    

        System.out.println(ySum);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
pool-1-thread-3 returns 26619
pool-1-thread-5 returns 0
pool-1-thread-1 returns 104302
pool-1-thread-2 returns 95981
pool-1-thread-4 returns 23098
250000
```